# Converting a list of large objects to a list of subset objects

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of Alarm objects that are quite large having many fields that are used for internal calculations. The user of my Web API need only calculated values (but full alarm objects) that they convert through JSON call such as (omitting code for error checking):

```
string apiAddress = "api/Alarms/getDigitalAlarms";
HttpResponseMessage response = await DAServer.GetAsync(apiAddress);
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Alarm>>(result);
```

The Alarm class defined at their end, has only the fields that they need, with same property names and datatypes as defined at my end.

When we inspect the network traffic generated in json format, it contains the full alarm objects including inside sub-objects for each Alarm object (total of more than 1500 alarms). The extra information is discarded and never used by JsonConvert.DeserializeObject call above but why generate so much unneeded traffic in the first place?

Is there a "quicker way" of converting my large alarm objects to MiniAlarm objects (that have same skeleton as at the user end) before returning the list? Quicker because this call to API is made each second to see if some alarm is raised.

Comment: What I am saying might be obvious, but you are approaching the problem from wrong side. Seems like you are using web api and instead of requesting all alerts, they should provide method to filter them(let's say by date) or what would be even better is to push them to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `MiniAlarm` class with a constructor that takes in `Alarm` as a parameter then use LINQ and a projection as follows:

```
var result = myAlarms.Select(x=> new MiniAlarm(x)).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you could look into [ODATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/) on .NET - I've used it before and it works well.

You could of course also add a `[JsonIgnore]` tag over the members you don't care about in class `Alarm`if this is the only serialization happening.

Comment: It should be no slower than serializing them all as you are now. Probably faster.

Comment: Hmmm.... Let me try this and see if it consumes more time than my application can tolerate. Thenks a bunch!

NB: Serialization is taking place at the user's end (i.e. after receiving my response).

Comment: I somehow ignored the last part of your answer. [JsonIgnore] was the trick :) I just wanted those unneeded fields not to be part of the json output! I didn't know about this useful tag. It saved me all the conversion time. Thumbs up for you @Matt!